# Discord.js (v13) - Edit a message using a dropdown menu

Tags: discord.js

I would like to make a dropdown menu that edits its own "parent" message. *(The message is a response to a slash command interaction)*
My code now looks like this:

```
const row = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new MessageSelectMenu()
            .setCustomId('row')
            .setPlaceholder('Letter')
            .addOptions([
                {
                    label: 'A',
                    value: 'A',
                },
                {
                     label: 'B',
                     value: 'B',
                },
                {
                    label: 'C',
                    value: 'C',
                },
                {
                    label: 'D',
                    value: 'D',
                },
            ]),
    ); // End of .addComponents()
interaction.reply({content: "Select a letter!", components: [row]})

client.on("interactionCreate", async menuInteraction => {
    if (!menuInteraction.isSelectMenu()) return;
                        
    switch (menuInteraction.values[0]) {
        case "A":  
            interaction.editReply("A")
            break;
        case "B":  
            interaction.editReply("B")
            break;
        case "C": 
            interaction.editReply("C")
            break;
        case "D":
            interaction.editReply("D")
            break;
    };                
});
```

The code works fine. However, I found a bug that I can't fix.
When I summon the slash command more than once and I select an option in the last message's dropdown menu, both messages gets edited.

Is there any way to fix that?
I guess I should check if the slash command's reply message id is the same as the dropdown menu interaction's message id somehow, but I have no idea how to get the slash command's reply message. As I know the `client.user.lastMessage()` got removed in v13 so I can't   use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have an event (client.on ...) in the same file. This means that everytime you run the command an event listener gets created. You should put it in a seperate file and only call it once.

There you can use [Interaction.update()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/SelectMenuInteraction?scrollTo=update)
`menuInteraction.update(menuInteraction.values[0])`
(no need for the switch statement)